# mysql sorting data in two levels possible?

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to analyze some date from a mysql table.

The data is a representation of incomming calls, each line represents one call

```
category  purpose
cars      question
bikes     question
cars      question
cars      complaints
scooters  question
bikes     complaints
```

now for the plotting I need the data to look like this

```
category cat_count question complaints
cars     3         2        1
bikes    2         1        1
scooters 1         1
```

I figured out that I can sort and count by one field by using something like this

```
SELECT category, count(*) FROM stat GROUP BY category ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

which will give me

```
category   count
cars       3
bikes      2
scooters   1
```

but how can I add the purpose counts to that output?

I would usually write a php or bash script, but if its possible to do it in mysql I would rather do it like that instead of having a 3 loop script noone will understand in 1 year :-))

Thanks in advance for any hint (even if the hint is "impossible")

Comment: `question` `complaints` 2 fields fixed, or there will more fields like `question` `complaints`, `query`??

Comment: the two fields are fixed. I extracted these relevant-data from a larger table to keep the script as easy and understandable as possible.
or do you mean the data content? It is also fixed strings that the operator selects from a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
SELECT category, count(*) as cat_count, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN purpose='question' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN purpose='complaints' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as complaints
FROM stat 
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

**Result:**

```
CATEGORY    CAT_COUNT   QUESTION    COMPLAINTS
cars        3           2           1
bikes       2           1           1
scooters    1           1           0
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c207e4/5).

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try tonight it looks reasonably understandable, and sensfull. I'll post the result

Comment: of course!! I have tried it quickly with 2 fields. Semms to work. WOW and how quick this type of query is, compared to a bash script ;-)